ownCloud OpenID authentication with Keyrock
I'm currently trying to enable OpenId authentication for my ownCloud server with my Keyrock IdM. After working through a couple of issues that I was able to solve, I'm now stuck on a redirect issue after the authentication. The problem shows as follows:

Open owncloud website and click on "Other authentication - Keyrock".
Redirect to Keyrock website to login
After successful login, I can see a redirect to https://owncloud-URL/index.php/apps/files
This site then redirects to https://Keyrock-URL/auth/external_logout
I'm left on the Keyrock website logged in with the user that I wanted to use to access ownCloud.

The user exists in both databases for Keyrock and ownCloud.
This is how the app is configured in Keyrock:
App configuration in Keyrock.
Here is my full config.php for ownCloud:
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'ocvrrm37vlb3',
  'passwordsalt' => 'f/WUinwB4gevT0xOH/FCFeWrwbGSCg',
  'secret' => 'bSqTijtrHYVO6/nvFqns8GAdgo75opum0BZMk2GeURvMRAMG',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => '172.24.100.225',
    1 => '192.168.1.110',
    2 => 'owncloud',
    3 => 'owncloud.apollo.internal',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/media/owncloud_data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://owncloud',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '10.13.4.1',
  'dbname' => 'owncloud',
  'dbconnectionstring' => '',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'oc_admin',
  'dbpassword' => 'tqDyElLG/5brYoskw3xDdHlfWIXDDL',
  'allow_user_to_change_mail_address' => '',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'http.cookie.samesite' => 'None',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps-external',
      'url' => '/apps-external',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'installed' => true,
  'filelocking.enabled' => true,
  'memcache.locking' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\Redis',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\Redis',
  'redis' => 
  array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'timeout' => 0,
    'password' => '',
    'dbindex' => 0,
  ),
  'debug' => true,
  'log_type' => 'errorlog',
  'openid-connect' => 
  array (
    'auto-provision' => 
    array (
      'enabled' => false,
    ),
    'autoRedirectOnLoginPage' => false,
    'client-id' => '3f0e88da-5eca-4239-b564-940810f65e25',
    'client-secret' => '4848813d-8dbc-445c-b410-0951cc41db68',
    'loginButtonName' => 'Keyrock',
    'mode' => 'email',
    'search-attribute' => 'email',
    'provider-url' => 'https://keyrock2.apollo.internal/idm/applications/3f0e88da-5eca-4239-b564-940810f65e25',
  ),
);

The last entries of the diagnostic log are here:
{"type":"QUERY","reqId":"Zhxb4xWrgCEaaJmZFlkQFwAAAAY","diagnostics":{"sqlStatement":"SELECT * FROM `oc_appconfig`","sqlParams":"array ( )","sqlQueryDurationmsec":0.33402442932128906,"sqlTimestamp":1713134563.590297}}
{"type":"QUERY","reqId":"Zhxb4xWrgCEaaJmZFlkQFwAAAAY","diagnostics":{"sqlStatement":"SELECT * FROM `oc_accounts` WHERE `lower_user_id` = :dcValue1","sqlParams":"array (   'dcValue1' => 'clark@test.com', )","sqlQueryDurationmsec":0.1571178436279297,"sqlTimestamp":1713134563.593833}}
{"type":"QUERY","reqId":"Zhxb4xWrgCEaaJmZFlkQFwAAAAY","diagnostics":{"sqlStatement":"SELECT `appid`, `configkey`, `configvalue` FROM `oc_preferences` WHERE `userid` = ?","sqlParams":"array (   0 => 'clark@test.com', )","sqlQueryDurationmsec":0.10895729064941406,"sqlTimestamp":1713134563.596098}}
{"type":"QUERY","reqId":"Zhxb4xWrgCEaaJmZFlkQFwAAAAY","diagnostics":{"sqlStatement":"DELETE FROM `oc_authtoken` WHERE `token` = :token","sqlParams":"array (   'token' => 'b160cea1bb3f4799cb5cb7ee4dacb5ebdd32a35cfffe88fab185aa0aef651c95df041f2aeca34f5881e49d324749cd2e1261216871c98ec339c3df334ddfe981', )","sqlQueryDurationmsec":2.6471614837646484,"sqlTimestamp":1713134563.639561}}
{"type":"SUMMARY","reqId":"Zhxb4xWrgCEaaJmZFlkQFwAAAAY","time":"2024-04-14T22:42:43+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.2","user":"--","method":"GET","url":"\/index.php\/apps\/files\/","diagnostics":{"totalSQLQueries":4,"totalSQLDurationmsec":3.2472610473632812,"totalSQLParams":3,"totalEvents":8,"totalEventsDurationmsec":103.2721996307373}}

With the other issues I had I was able to work through the messages I got in the browser console but this one really brings me to my limits. Can you help me figure this out? I wasn't quite sure what config files are necessary but I hope I have the most important ones.
Edit: I also included an example of a JWT:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.Ou2f4eSe3sASTv4VFjHy0EJULJzFyVNtx2FaDMO5uz8

Thank you!
